# How do I pass a class property value to a method in another class

Tags: c#

I have a simple class:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }

        public void PrintName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name:{0} Age:{1}", Name, Age); //<= I can print Name & Age
        }

        public static (double A, double B) DoSomething(string someString)
        {
            double distance = AnotherClass.AnotherMethod(Name, Age); //<= VS will not allow me to pass Name & Age.
        }
    }
}
```

How do I pass the values of Name & Age to a method in another class?

Comment: your DoSomething is **static**. static methods do not have access to non-static properties, which exist only for an **instance** of your class. just make the method non-static.

Comment: You can't access instance members in static context

Comment: In any case, I would probably pass 'this' instead of tbe individual properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this for the static method. Remove 'static' word and it will work.